# Strange behavior: Undefined index whilst index IS correct

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm trying to access a value from an array that is 3 levels deep yet PHP is reporting that the index is undefined whilst it certainly is. Unset using the same index works fine!

Code:

```
function CleanUpCharacters($c) //Remove unneeded information
{   
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($c); ++$i)
    {
        $c[$i]['character']['rank'] = $c[$i]['rank']; // Move rank in to char
        $c[$i] = $c[$i]['character']; // Move subarray char's keys/values to parent array

        unset($c[$i]['battlegroup']);
        unset($c[$i]['level']);
        unset($c[$i]['achievementPoints']);
        unset($c[$i]['thumbnail']);

        $c[$i]['specName'] = $c[$i]['spec']; // <--- Undefined index notice
        unset($c[$i]['spec']); // <--- Works fine, no errors

        unset($c[$i]['guild']);
        unset($c[$i]['guildRealm']);
    }

    return $c;
}
```

The line causes the error is actually `$c[$i]['specName'] = $c[$i]['spec']['name']`; I removed `['name']` to see if that fixed the issue but it did not.

Here's a screenshot of the unfiltered array, `$c`:

[image]

Comment: I guess `spec` is inside `character`. So shouldn't it be `$c[$i]['character']['spec']['name']` ? Or is it just a typo somewhere?

Comment: The 2nd line within the `for` loop removes the need for `['character']`!

Comment: Oops! Sorry my bad, didn't see it first. Ok - the rest looks pretty good. Did you try inserting `print_r($c[$i])` just before the offending line? The output there might give an idea as to what's going wrong and would be helpful for us to solve if you can paste that too.

Comment: maybe some of the arrays, (since the output picture is truncated) has really undefined indices, just use isset, check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unset() always works. It has no return value and it won't raise an error or notice.

Unset example with undefined var: http://ideone.com/4OcSkQ

```
<?php 
unset($a);
```

In your code, you need a key existance check, before you can do the assignment.

```
    $c[$i]['specName'] = $c[$i]['spec']; // <--- Undefined index notice
```

becomes

```
    if(array_key_exists('spec', $c[$i]) === true) { // test, if spec key exists
       $c[$i]['specName'] = $c[$i]['spec'];         // assign from spec to specName
    }
```

If you need to log or process the opposite case (when spec is missing), you might add an else:

```
    else {
        echo 'Key "spec" was not found. Working on: ' . $i['name'] . '<br>';
    }
```

Also you can delete more then one variable with unset(), like so:

```
    unset(
       $c[$i]['battlegroup'], 
       $c[$i]['level'], 
       $c[$i]['achievementPoints'], 
       $c[$i]['thumbnail']
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any error here. It seems that for some records `spec` may be not set. You can check it changing:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($c); ++$i) {
```

into

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($c); ++$i) {
   if (!isset($c[$i]['character']['spec']) {
       echo "no spec in array! for ".$i."<br />";
   }
```